# Markdown not rendering properly in django

Tags: django, django-templates, markdown

I am using markdown in django 1.11 and I implemented it using cdn
but when ever I run the site, the first paragraph is rendered inside pre and code tags.

Below is the screenshot which is rendered:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqNKI.png

Here every first para is rendered like that in every post why is it so and please help me to resolve it.

post_detail.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="card mb-3">
        {% if list.image %}
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ list.image.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
        {% endif %}
        <div class="card-block">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{ list.title }}</h3>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Author: 
                {% if list.user.get_full_name %}
                    {{ list.user.get_full_name }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ list.user }}
                {% endif %}
            </small></p>
            <div class="content-marked">
                <p class="card-text">{{ list.content }}</p>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated {{list.updated | timesince}} ago</small></p>
            <a href="{% url 'posts:edit' list.slug %}" class="card-link">Edit</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: We need some more info . Can you provide the value of `list.content`? Also the HTML output of your template (use "view source" in your browser and copy/paste the HTML text as screen captures are not much help in debugging Markdown).

Comment: List.content contains the text like a normal post text

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44632031/edit) your question to include an example.

Comment: Also, what are you using to render your Markdown to HTML?